# How to resolve paho-mqtt python scripts import error?

Tags: python, mqtt

Currently using paho-mqtt for a project.

In publish.py the import statement: from . import client as paho

I have the following error:

ImportError: Attempted relative import with no known parent package

In client.py the import statement: from .subscribeoptions import SubscribeOptions

I have the following error:

ImportError: Attempted relative import with no known parent package

Might anyone know why this may be happening? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try reinstalling the package or using from a venv. What code are you using to import the package?

Comment: Edit the question to actually include the code (and format it)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have now resolved the error.